# glht function in R giving different results compared to calculations done by hand

Tags: r, anova, calculation, hypothesis-test

I am coding an example and comparing with results obtained by hand however the results are not consistent. The data set is about a study comparing a score for 3 different treatments. The data set can be reproduced  as follows (relabelled for convenience).

```
Score = c(12, 11, 15, 11, 10, 13, 10, 4, 15, 16, 9, 14, 10, 6, 10, 8, 11, 12,
          12, 8,12, 9, 11, 15, 10, 15, 9, 13, 8, 12, 10, 8, 9, 5, 12,4, 6, 9, 4, 7, 7, 7,
          9, 12, 10, 11, 6, 3, 4, 9, 12, 7, 6, 8, 12, 12, 4, 12,13, 7, 10, 13, 9, 4, 4,
          10, 15, 9,5, 8, 6, 1, 0, 8, 12, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 7, 7, 12, 7, 9, 7, 9, 5, 11, 9, 5,
          6, 8,8, 6, 7, 10, 9, 4, 8, 7, 3, 1, 4, 3)

Treatment = c(rep("T1",35), rep("T2",33), rep("T3",37))

medicine = data.frame(Score, Treatment)
```

We can get the group means and the ANOVA as follows:

```
> aggregate(medicine$Score ~ medicine$Treatment, FUN = mean)
  medicine$Treatment medicine$Score
1                 T1      10.714286
2                 T2       8.333333
3                 T3       6.513514

> anova.model = aov(Score ~ Treatment, dat = medicine)
> anova(anova.model)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Score
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Treatment   2 318.51 159.255   17.51 2.902e-07 ***
Residuals 102 927.72   9.095                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Suppose we wanted to conduct the following hypothesis test using a contrast:

```
# H0 : mu_1 = (mu_2 + mu_3) / 2
# Ha : mu_1 != (mu_2 + mu_3) / 2
```

where `!=` means "not equal to". We can re-write the hypotheses as:

```
# H0 : mu_1 - (mu_2)/2 - (mu_3)/2 = 0
# Ha : mu_1 - (mu_2)/2 - (mu_3)/2 != 0
```

This gives us the contrast coefficients of c1=1, c2=-1/2 and c3=-1/2

If I use the sample means to calculate the contrast gamma-hat by hand, we get

```
# gamma-hat = (c1)(x-bar_1) + (c2)(x-bar_2) + (c3)(x-bar_3)
# gamma-hat = (1)(10.714286) - (1/2)(8.333333) - (1/2)(6.513514) = 3.290862
```

However I do not get this result using the `glht()` function in the `multcomp` library:

```
> # run code above
>
> library(multcomp)
>
> # declare contrast with coefficients corresponding to those in hypothesis test
> contrast = matrix(c(1, -1/2, -1/2), nrow = 1)
>
> # anova model declared earlier
> contrast.model = glht(anova.model , linfct = contrast)
> summary(contrast.model)

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: aov(formula = Score ~ Treatment, data = medicine)

Linear Hypotheses:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
1 == 0   14.005      1.082   12.95   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

From the output obtained, we see that the estimate of `gamma-hat` is 14.005 and it is not 3.290862 which is the value obtained when I calculated `gamma-hat` by hand. I can show that the standard error obtained is also different to the standard error calculated by hand if desired.

I used the same technique on a different data set and the results were consistent when calculated by hand and using `glht` so I'm not sure where my error is.

Can someone please help me figure out where I am going wrong with either my code or calculation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

14.005 is correct. If you look at the fit of your anova model, you did not include an intercept, so T1 is taken as the reference and the coefficients reflect how much different groups deviate from the reference mean (T1)

```
coefficients(anova.model)
```

it returns

```
(Intercept) TreatmentT2 TreatmentT3 
  10.714286   -2.380952   -4.200772
```

For example, T2, the coefficient is -2.38 because it's mean is -2.38 + 10.712 = 8.3  If you calculate the difference using the contrast you specified:

```
coefficients(anova.model)%*%t(contrast)
```

You get the same estimate as coefficients(contrast.model).

To get what you wanted above, you have to do:

```
anova.model = aov(Score ~ 0+Treatment, dat = medicine)
contrast.model <- glht(anova.model , linfct = contrast)
```

Comment: multcomp can be a bit a handful. I used this book a long time again, in case you need it:
(http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio_N/R_Eng/Bretz2011.pdf)

Comment: This e-book will be very helpful! Thank you so much for sharing it!